# Certificate enrollment request chain not trusted

Tags: windows, active-directory, certificate

I am working on a MSFT lab for Direct Access, and need to create a Web certificate.  The instructions ask be to do the following:

> 1. On EDGE1, click Start, type mmc, and then press ENTER. Click Yes at the User Account Control prompt.
> 2. Click File, and then click Add/Remove Snap-ins.
> 3. Click Certificates, click Add, click Computer account, click Next, select Local computer, click Finish, and then click OK.
> 4. In the console tree of the Certificates snap-in, open Certificates (Local Computer)\Personal\Certificates.
> 5. Right-click Certificates, point to All Tasks, and then click Request New Certificate.
> 6. Click Next twice.
> 7. On the Request Certificates page, click Web Server, and then click More information is required to enroll for this certificate.
> 8. On the Subject tab of the Certificate Properties dialog box, in Subject name, for Type, select Common Name.
> 9. In Value, type edge1.contoso.com, and then click Add.
> 10. Click OK, click Enroll, and then click Finish.
> 11. In the details pane of the Certificates snap-in, verify that a new certificate with the name edge1.contoso.com was enrolled with Intended
>       Purposes of Server Authentication.
> 12. Right-click the certificate, and then click Properties.
> 13. In Friendly Name, type IP-HTTPS Certificate, and then click OK.
> 14. Close the console window. If you are prompted to save settings, click No.

In production, our company has overridden the **Web Server** template and it doesn't seem to be issuing certificates with the full CA chain.  When I look at the issued certificate properties then both tiers of the 2 tier CA hierarchy are missing.

How can I fix this?  I'm not sure where to look outside the GUI.

Comment: What are you using to look at the certificate's properties, and what format is the certificate in (or is it in a computer's certificate store)?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I'm looking in the computer cert store, and the cert is located in "Pending Certificates" even after I approve the cert on the server

Comment: Oh, it doesn't allow enrollment without approval on the CA?  In that case, export the approved certificate from the CA - it'll need to be manually imported to complete the request from the web server.